# How to find a date X% between two dates using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, sql, automationstudio

I need to find what the date is X% between two date fields. The use case is I want to send an email to someone who is 70% of the way through their tenancy.

For example,

```
Move-in date = 01/01/20
Move-out date = 31/01/20
Reminder date (70%) = 22/01/20
```

Is there a simple way to do this within one SQL? From what I've found so far, it's possible to find the percentage, but not the date it equates to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the functions `DateAdd`, `DateDiff` and a multiplication. The query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, movein, moveout)*0.7, movein) as [reminder_date]
FROM
  exampletable
```

For your example this results in the date `2020-01-22`.

**Further resources:**

- [DateAdd function reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [DateDiff function reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)