# How to identify the % of time between two dates + how to find records between two dates using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, date

Relating to my question related to [finding a date X% between two dates using SQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305977/how-to-find-a-date-x-between-two-dates-using-sql/305984#305984), I'm having a challenge resolving two other similar things:

1. How to identify the % of time between two dates. Here's what I tried, which didn't seem to work. I tried GETDATE() instead of NOW() and that didn't work either:

```
    SELECT  
    ((DATEDIFF(NOW() - Moveindate__c) / (Moveoutdate__c - Moveindate__c) ) *100 as [tenancy_percentage]  
    FROM X
```

2. How to identify only records where today is between two dates in a WHERE clause. Here's what I tried, which didn't work:

```
    WHERE Request.Moveoutdate__c BETWEEN (Request.Moveindate__c) AND (Request.Moveoutdate__c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Now()" is an AMPScript function, rather than an SQL function and logically Request.Moveoutdate__c will always be between Request.Moveindate__c and Request.Moveoutdate__c.

It sounds like you're looking for something along these lines:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  DATEDIFF(day,Moveindate__c,GETDATE()) / DATEDIFF(day,Moveindate__c,Moveoutdate__c) * 100 AS PercentComplete
FROM 
  Request
WHERE 
  GETDATE() BETWEEN Moveindate__c AND Moveoutdate__c
```

Comment: Thanks @Macca. The query validated and it populated with records as expected, however the PercentageComplete field returned with a 0 value. I've tried setting the field type to Percentage, Number, and Text. Is there a step missing in defining the field type in the query?

Comment: I'd probably create as something like Decimal(18,2) for your field, unless you need whole numbers and use the SQL Convert function to set your PercentComplete field to the same data type - Decimal(18,2). Also, make sure that the field names in your Data Extension match the aliases for field names in the query - they must match exactly.